# improve linq call to make one db call

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Can I have some help in improving this linq. I'm basically returning speakers from the db but setting HasNew property true if there has been a video by them posted in the past week.

```
   public IQueryable<Speaker> GetSpeakers()
    {
        var speakers =  db.Speakers.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
        var newVidsSpeakers = db.Videos.Where(x => x.DatePosted > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).Select(x=> x.Speaker).Distinct();
        foreach (var item in newVidsSpeakers)
        {
            var sp = speakers.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID);
            sp.HasNew = true;
        }
        return speakers;
    }
```

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using?

Comment: You can use [Join operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you making the second call anyway? You should just be able to do:

```
public IQueryable<Speaker> GetSpeakers()
{
    var speakers = db.Speakers.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
    var newVidsSpeakers = db.Videos.Where(x => x.DatePosted > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)).Select(x => x.Speaker).Distinct();
    foreach (var speaker in newVidsSpeakers)
    {
        speaker.HasNew = true;
    }
    return speakers;
}
```

Comment: can the call for speakers and videos be merged into 1?

Comment: actually i just realised this is not what is slowing me down, it's something else... thanks for this anyway

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what LINQ provider you are using (e.g. the default LINQ To SQL or a Object Relational Mapper like [Mindscape Lightspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/lightspeed) or [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org)) or information on the database schema it is difficult to give *any* advice.

So until that is known, the best thing that I can do is re-arrange the LINQ statements to give the chosen provider more knowledge/context so that it can better optimise query thus possibly reduce the number of database calls.

**Note:** You may find that it is not possible to reduce this to a **single** database call.

This is how I would have written a similar query.

```
public IEnumerable<Speaker> GetSpeakers()
{
    var speakers = db.Speakers;
    var lastWeek = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);
    var recentVideos = db.Videos.Where(x => (x.DatePosted.Date >= lastWeek)).ToArray();
    
    foreach (var speaker in speakers)
        speaker.HasNew = recentVideos.Any(x => (x.Speaker == speaker));
        
    return speakers.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName);
}
```

- Get the speakers unordered as perform ordering to late as possible. If the ordering is for presentation then do it later in the in the view.
- Store what the **date** was last week. I'm using `DateTime.Now.Date` and `x.DataPosted.Date` so that we are not comparing the time, i.e., you want to find all videos since last week even if you search at 11:59pm.
- Find all recent videos as an array so that we do not enumerate the collection multiple times in the next part.
- Iterate over all the speakers and check if that speaker has any recent videos.
- Then, if required, order the speakers by display name.